# Rails String in View with whitespaces

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, string, view

I'm trying to show a string with xml content (correct with whitespaces  etc.) in a rails view.

My Controller action read a xml file and put this content into a string. 
For example

```
  @xml_content = "
     <main>
      <children>
         <a>
         </a>
         <b>
         </b>
      </children>
    </main>
    "
```

Then I get this string from my controller and want to show this xml content in a view.

```
<%= @xml_content %>
```

But when I print this string in the view all whitespaces get lost and I get something like this:

```
     <main><children><a></a><b></b></children></main>
```

Printing the same string in the console with "puts @xml_content" create the correct output.

What can I do to show this xml content with all whitespaces in the view?

**EDIT:**
Controller:

```
@file = File.open(@xml_device_description.get_file_path)

@xml_content = Nokogiri::XML @file
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To conserve whitespaces of your content, you can wrap it in a `pre` tag.

```
<pre>
 <%= @xml_content %>
</pre>
```

Comment: Is there a possibility to format the string or to use a kind of syntax highlighting?